# A bootable usb key prevent system to boot

Tags: bios, boot, dd

I'm written a ChromiumOS image on an usb key with the command `dd`. 
When I boot my computer with the usb key plugged, the start-up blocks just after the line describing the cpu, so before I can select on which device boot.

Here is the dd command I've used:

```
dd if=ChromeOS.img of=/dev/sdX bs=4M
```

as explained on the [hexxeh images page](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/)

Do you think that it's an hardware issue or a problem during the copy of the image (I've retried 3 times)?

Comment: i'm just curious - is this an HP computer? my tx2000 does the same thing, but only with ChromiumOS images and not other bootable USB images

Comment: Heh, my computer is an HP as well, must be an HP thing.

Comment: nop, it's a Packard Bell (at least, was a PB, but there's still the motherboard)

Comment: with ubuntu images, there's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

My computer has a similar problem when trying to boot with my Kindle plugged in. My solution was to disable booting from USB or not having the key plugged in when you boot the PC.

Comment: yes, but in that case, I can not boot on the usb key :)

Comment: Did you try a second USB key? Just trying to rule things out here.

Comment: yes, with no more success

Comment: Odd, have you tried multiple image versions? (In case it's a corrupted download or onetime bug)

Comment: yes. It must be a hardware issue. My motherboard is old, and not designed for supporting other than what was on it when I bought it

Comment: Have you considered updating the bios? though not without risk, it might be something to consider if you are not going to use this computer for anything else and you can find a newer image.

Comment: you're right, I'm going to try that :)